# Join data from two models to single dict

Tags: python, django

I am trying to combine the two models. I want to display in one endpoint a list of cars that are available per user along with the last registered fuel level.
Im looking for way to merge two models into single object.

My models.py file:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        cars = models.ManyToManyField('Car', related_name='users_cars')
    
class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    plate_no = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    
class FuelLevel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', on_delete=models.CASCADE())
    level = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py:

```
class CarsStatusesList(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        token_user_id = self.request.auth.payload['user_id']
        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=token_user_id).get()

        # Last levels for user cars
        levels = FuelLevel.objects\
            .filter(car__in=user.cars.all())\
            .order_by('car', '-timestamp')\
            .distinct('car')

        cars = user.cars.all()

        # How to merge cars with lastest fuel level. something like this:
         result = cars JOIN levels ON  " levels.car_id = cars._id "

        return JsonResponse(list(result.values()), safe=False)
```

I want to get response like this:

```
[{
  "car_id": 31,
  "brand" : "Ford"
  "model" : "Focus"
  "plate_no" : "XDS 12342"
  "level" : "80"
  "timestamp" : "2021-05-06 12:22"
  }, 
  "car_id": 4,
  "brand" : "Ford"
  "model" : "Mondeo"
  "plate_no" : "GYR 342"
  "level" : "20"
  "timestamp" : "2021-05-06 10:22"
  } 
]
```

Comment: Since any `Car` instance can only have one `FuelLevel`, why not make `level` and `timestamp` part of the `Car` model? Then you could just do `Car.objects.values()` to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [nested-relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). You'll have to create a serializer for each one of your models and declare their relationship.

Here's and example:

```
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Car, FuelLevel

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'

class FuelLevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car = CarSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FuelLevel
        fields = '__all__'


# views.py

from rest_framework import generics

from .serializers import FuelLevelSerializer
from .models import FuelLevel

class CarsStatusesList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FuelLevelSerializer
    queryset = FuelLevel.objects.all()

# Returns:
[
    {
        "car": {
            "id": 3,
            "brand": "Volvo",
            "model": "XC60",
            "plate_no" "ABC123",
        },
        "level": 23,
        "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
]
```